# I would like to purchase more disk drive space in google colab, i already have enouh google drive space

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am interested in purchasing more drive space inside of google colab. I was told if i payed for more google drive space it would give me colab space, it didnt

Comment: Voting to close as this does not seem to have anything to do with [the topics you can ask about on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can buy Google Drive space. This will increase the space of your Google Drive.

You can then mount the Google drive to your Google Colab, this will let you access your increased size from Colab.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

This is the code to mount the drive to your colab. After mounting you can see the new folder on your Folders section on the Colab notebook.